# The Values are not being dumped into the table temperature_demo

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have written this code to remove the duplicate entries from the table and then to insert it into the other table.
The code executes but the values are not being updated into the table.
Query4 is not getting executed.
Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thank you.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class duplicate
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Statement stat=null,stat1=null,stat2=null;
        Connection con=null;
        ResultSet result1,result2;
        int s_id=0;
        String date=null,time=null,temp=null;
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Loaded Driver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/preprocessor","root","bigdata");
            System.out.println("Connected to mysql");
            stat=con.createStatement();
            stat1=con.createStatement();
            stat2=con.createStatement();
            String query1="insert into temperature_demo(ddslno,ddtstation_id,ddtdate,ddttime,ddtemp,ddtype_code,ddelevation) select dslno,dtstation_id,dtdate,dttime,dtemp,dtype_code,delevation from temperature_dup where dslno=1";
            String query2="select * from temperature_demo";
            String query3="select * from temperature_dup";
            stat1.execute(query1);
            result1=stat1.executeQuery(query2);
            result2=stat2.executeQuery(query3);

                while(result1.next())
                {
                    s_id=result1.getInt(2);
                    date=result1.getString(3);
                    time=result1.getString(4);
                    temp=result1.getString(5);
                    break;
                }
                while(result2.next())
                {
                    int sno=result2.getInt(1);
                    int s1_id=result2.getInt(2);
                    String date1=result2.getString(3);
                    String time1=result2.getString(4);
                    String temp1=result2.getString(5);
                    String type_cd=result2.getString(6);
                    String elev=result2.getString(7);
                    String query4="insert into temperature_demo values(sno,s1_id,'date1','time1','temp1','type_cd','elev')";
                    try
                    {
                    if( (s_id==s1_id)&&(date.equals(date1))&&(time.equals(time1))&&(temp.equals(temp1)) )
                        ;
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(sno+" "+s1_id+" "+date1);
                        stat1.execute(query4);
                    }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(con!=null)
                try
                {
                    con.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            if(stat1!=null)
                try
                {
                    stat1.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            if(stat2!=null)
                try
                {
                    stat2.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the changes and the following code is the result.
    PreparedStatement pstat;
    pstat=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO temperature_demo VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    while(result2.next())
                    {
                        int sno=result2.getInt(1);
                        int s1_id=result2.getInt(2);
                        String date1=result2.getString(3);
                        String time1=result2.getString(4);
                        String temp1=result2.getString(5);
                        String type_cd=result2.getString(6);
                        String elev=result2.getString(7);

```
                    try
                    {
                    if( (s_id==s1_id)&&(date.equals(date1))&&(time.equals(time1))&&(temp.equals(temp1)) )
                        ;
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(sno+" "+s1_id+" "+date1);
                        pstat.setInt(1,sno);
                        pstat.setInt(2,s1_id);
                        pstat.setString(3,date1);
                        pstat.setString(4,time1);
                        pstat.setString(5,temp1);
                        pstat.setString(6,type_cd);
                        pstat.setString(7,elev);
                    }
```

The first statement in the else block seems to execute perfectly. The following pstat statements(pstat is a preparedStatement variable) aren't executing